# Existence of measurable fuction on non-atomic measure space whose integral is infinity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be non atomic measure space with $\mu(X)>0.$

Show that there is a measurable function $f:X\to [0,\infty),$ for which $\int f(x)d\mu(x)=\infty.$

No idea at all. I am preparing for qualifying so could you help me.

Comment: First find pairwise disjoint sets $A_1$, $A_2$, $\ldots$, each of positive measure. Then take $f$ to be of the form $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i\chi_{A_i}$ for appropriately chosen $\alpha_i$.